# Tomcat server (from XAMPP package) cannot be started from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, xampp

I am using Windows 7. I installed Eclipse and updated to include WPT. HTTP Server and Tomcat are installed with XAMPP Package. They run properly and they can be accessed via localhost.

But I found that tomcat server cannot be started. Eclipse always reports failed to start.

```
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(J)J
at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(Native Method)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:589)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1058)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:535)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:555)
... 6 more*
```

Is there anything that I can check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [HTTP 1.1 APR protocol](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html) (or at least, XAMPP has configured its Tomcat instance to use APR by default). This has dependencies on native libraries which should be included in the environment variable `%PATH%`. If those native libraries cannot be resolved, you'll get an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

So to fix this issue, you need to add the path to the APR libraries to the `%PATH%` or to change the `protocol` attribute of the [HTTP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) in `server.xml` to use the standard implementation `HTTP/1.1` or the NIO implementation `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol`.